# calculating minimum Euclidean distance within a data frame

Tags: matlab

I have a data frame

```
x=[1;2;3;4;5]
```

I would like to find the minimum Euclidean Distance (ED) . I did it manually because I am not good in programming. I hope somebody will help me.

The manual way that  did was :

```
assign the first data to a variable A
A=1;
assign the second data to a variable b
B=2;
assign the third data to variable C and so on until the last data.
find the ED
D1=norm(A-B);
find the second ED
D2=norm(B-C);
D3=norm(C-D);

find the minimum ED
minxED=min(D1,D2,D3)
```

please help me. I would like to expand the question a little bit..

now the data frame is in the matrix form of [3000 X 13].

how to calculate the ED of each row (total of 3000 row, and calculate the average of it?

Previously, I used the answer given below

```
y = min(abs(x(2:end) - x(1:end-1);
y1= min(abs(z(2:end) - z(1:end-1);
y2=min(abs(s(2:end) - s(1:end-1);
```

and then assign the answer to a variable ans;

```
an1=[y,y1,y2];
then find the average
avr=mean(an1);
```

how to do this? thanks a lot

Comment: First, never use variable `ans` in MATLAB. Secondly, what if the minimum ED occurs between data 1 and 4. Your method of comparing first-second, second-third, etc. will fail. If you think, what I have said is valid, then I have a better way of doing the same.

Comment: I don't follow what you are wanting with this addition to your question. It will help if you give a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks  @Ayb4btu..actually, what i want to do is to find the average minimum ED of each data frame . Each data frame is actually a set of speech sample. I need to find the minimum ED and of 3000 samples. than find the average of the minimum ED of the total sample. Referring to the expanded question, x is sample 1, z is sample 2 and s is sample 3. So I really need to find the minimum ED of each of them. I hope this explanation will make the question clearer. Please help me

Comment: thanks @Parag, I will take note on the 'ans'.

Comment: @user3471465 Unfortunately that doesn't really make it any clearer. Maybe start with what you want from the Euclidean distance.

Comment: Hi @Ayb4btu, I already edit the question...actually, the data is in the form of matrix..it is the answer I got from previous process..after that I want to calculate the ED..thanks

Comment: @user3471465 You want the Euclidean distance of each row? So you want `norm(x)` (where `x` is a row)? At the moment you are getting the L1 distance between adjacent elements in the `x`. Can you please explain more clearly what you expect/want from the Euclidean distance.

Comment: What do you mean by minimum ED of each data frame. Let's say your frame is `x=[1; 8; 4; 2; 20]`. Can you calculate the minimum ED by hand and tell me here? If I understand correctly, it should be `1`.

Comment: Actually, the minimum ED indicates a stable data of the frame. from my understanding, if lets say, row 1 has 0.01 ED, row 2 0.2 ED this indicates that raw 1 is more stable.

Comment: I dont know if I am wrong, but actually, the data in each raw is the measurement of each framed based signal. it is located at different places in the x-y graph.Please correct me if I am wrong,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I followed your question correctly then it would seem that you want something like this:

```
minxED = min(abs(x(2:end) - x(1:end-1)));
```

which gets the L1 distance between adjacent elements in the vector `x` and then finds the minimum distance.

Comment: Hi Benoit_11, thanks for the reminder..however I am really sorry, can u guide me how to accept the answer please? because I tried to click at the up error on the left of the answer but it require 15 reputation. thanks

Comment: @user3471465 - Click on the checkmark icon underneath the up and down arrows.